# REST API path using route parameters without identifiers

Tags: rest, express, url, router

Using expressjs term [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) to show my problem, I also see people call that [path parameters](https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/docapis_doc_parameters.html#path_parameters). The "proper" URL will be

```
Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
```

But currently I am taking over a project that design the api like this,

```
/:userId/:bookId
/:groupId/:userId/some_resurce
...
```

The obvious problem is when I look at the url from browser I will feel confused with what those parameters mean, like the following. But the project has run for more than one year, I need to know whether it is worth the effort to rewrite it.

So is there other problem with the URL like these ?

[image: router parameters]

Comment: To really understand how to create routes for an API, we need to look at what type of data structure is being stored, and what you're planning to expose to the outer world.

Maybe could you share more on that, so that we have a good example to discuss on.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there's an issue?

Comment: I am not sure and hence the question, except for the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there other problem with the URL like these ?

They might be making extra work for your operators when reading the access logs?

---

REST doesn't care about URI spelling conventions - until you get to the origin server, a URI is effectively an opaque string; only the origin server has the authority to decompose the URI into its semantic parts.

Which is to say, general purpose components don't care that there are identifiers encoded into the path, or that the semantics of those identifiers changes depending on other path elements.

In particular, they don't care at all that unrelated identifiers have common elements:

```
/1/2
/1/2/some_resource
```

As far as a general purpose component is concerned, the resources identified here have no special relationship to one another.  (For example, if you DELETE /1/2, that's not expected to impact /1/2/some_resource in any way).

---

> when I look at the url from browser I will feel confused with what those parameters mean

Yup - this is your primary argument: that the current URI design doesn't consider human affordances.

Unless you can make a case that those human focused considerations (users, operators, tech writers) offset the costs of change, you are probably stuck with it.